# Numbering paragraphs in Python

Tags: python, text-files

I have to write a function with two parameters, infilename and outfilename. I have to take the lines from infilename and write the new lines into the outfilename. The infile is text that looks like this.

```
My essay is kind of short. It
is only going to have a few inarticulate
lines and even
fewer paragraphs.


The second paragraph
has arrived, and you can see
it's not much.

The third paragraph now arrives
and departs as hastily.
```

It is my objective to number the lines so that the output looks like this:

```
1,  1 My essay is kind of short. It
1,  2 is only going to have a few inarticulate
1,  3 lines and even
1,  4 fewer paragraphs.
0,  5
0,  6
0,  7
2,  8 The second paragraph
2,  9 has arrived, and you can see
2, 10 it's not much.
0, 11
0, 12
3, 13 The third paragraph now arrives
3, 14 and departs as hastily.
```

So I need to keep track of the number of the paragraph, as well as each individual line. I tried while loops but they didnd't seem fruitful. The amount of progress I have made on this problem is very minimal. I am very good at formatting, but I'm not sure how to keep track of what paragraph it is or when there are multiple '\n'. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Basically, a new paragraph is created upon finding a newline.

Comment: Set variables to keep track of the current paragraph number and current line number within the paragraph. Loop through the lines of the file, and increment each appropriately (the line number for each row, and the paragraph number when you hit a new paragraph). Hint: How can you tell when you've hit the end of a paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    p = 1    
    for i, l in enumerate(lines):            
        if not l.strip():            
            print " {},{} {}".format(0,i+1,l)
            if  lines[i + 1].strip():
                p += 1 
        else:
            print " {},{} {}".format(p,i+1,l)
```

Outputs:

```
1,1 My essay is kind of short. It
1,2 is only going to have a few inarticulate
1,3 lines and even
1,4 fewer paragraphs.
0,5
0,6
0,7
2,8 The second paragraph
2,9 has arrived, and you can see
2,10 it's not much.
0,11
0,12
3,13 The third paragraph now arrives
3,14 and departs as hastily.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I didn't just do your homework, but here you go..

```
with open("example.txt") as f:
  content = f.readlines()

line_count = 0
paragraph_count = 0
last_line = ""
for line in content:
    line = line.strip()
    if last_line == "" and len(line) > 1:
        paragraph_count += 1
    line_count += 1
    last_line = line

    print "[%d][%d] %s" % (line_count, paragraph_count, line)
```

Comment: Most of this works and I appreciate the answer, but it appears that the blank lines aren't 0, they're just the number of the paragraph preceding it.

Comment: Well I figured you could figure out if the line length is 0, then to put a 0 :)  I didn't want to completely do your home work..

Answer (score 0):

```
outfile = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
lastline = ""

linenum = 1
paranum = 1

with open('infile.txt') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if line != "\n" and lastline == "\n":
            paranum += 1

        if line != "\n":
            newline = "%d, %-*d %s" % (paranum, len(str(len(lines))), linenum, line)
            outfile.write(newline)

        if line == "\n":
            newline = "%d, %-*d %s" % (0, len(str(len(lines))), linenum, line)
            outfile.write(newline)

        lastline = line
        linenum += 1
```